# Laser scanning: why are things like deflection and mirrors used instead of just a mount and servo?

Tags: servo, optoelectronics, optics, photonics

In the [Wikipedia article for laser scanning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_scanning), it is said that laser scanning is the controlled **deflection** of laser beams, visible or invisible. It then lists some of the technologies used, such as mirrors. But why is deflection necessary? Why do we need to use these intermediary components, such as mirrors, to direct the laser beam? In particular, couldn't we just attach the laser to a servo, as done [here](https://youtu.be/oJAl9Yd3kNo) and [here](https://youtu.be/iH9_xtulyws), and do laser scanning in this way? What benefit does deflection have over using a servo? It seems to me that using the intermediary components for deflection is just superfluous, outside of, perhaps, specialized use-cases.

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to explain this to me.

Comment: @Sanmvegsaini All of the deflection technologies are implemented *using* mechanical components (such as servos); otherwise, how would we expect them to move? For instance, see servo-controlled galvanometers (mirrors) here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_scanning#Scanning_mirrors

Comment: Safety, when the laser stops moving it becomes more hazardous for eyes due to reaction time.

Comment: Actually there are scanners that move the laser assembly like the Velodyne HDL-32E and HFL-64E.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Interesting. But why would you need to move the entire assembly? Can't you just move the laser diode itself, which is very small and light?

Comment: You need precise timing between the emitter and the detector, so putting those in the same assembly together with some of the driving electronics makes the most sense.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Ahh, yes, you're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few thoughts:

- Weight: moving a lightweight mirror will be easier than moving the laser assembly.
- Speed: related to weight, the system response can be much faster.
- Reliability: no flexing of wires which may fracture or break.
- Infinite rotation: Mirrors can be made in a prism fashion to do a raster scan by continuous rotation. (See the checkout laser scanners for example.) With constant rotation speed there is no non-linearity caused by acceleration and deceleration.

Comment: With regards to weight: Laser diodes are extremely low-weight, no?

Comment: And just to clarify something that I'm wondering after reading your last point: Aren't prisms different optical components to mirrors (that is, they are separate categories/types of optical components)?

Comment: @ThePointer Prisms are different to mirrors. Prisms are mentioned in the wiki article you linked to, and are used for mechanical deflection of laser beams, so belong in this answer. Some laser diodes are lowish weight, though not as low as a mirror. If you need a bigger laser, it will be heavier, while the mirror will still be as light.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Laser diodes are pretty small, but they need collimation optics (lenses) on. At low power these can be made of plastic. Still heavier than a mirror. At high power, the laser plus optics becomes a substantial weight of glass, possibly with its own cooling.

Comment: Checkout scanner are usually (always?) polygon mirrors rather then prisms since they're literally just a motor and a 10 or 12 side polygon mirror which is a cheap as it gets. Refractive prism scanners exist too, but they're more complex.

Comment: @user1850479 "Refractive prism scanners" like Risley prisms?

Comment: @ThePointer  Yes, see: https://www.thorlabs.com/images/tabimages/Risley_Prism_Scanner_App_Note.pdf  Downside is that you need two motors to scan a line (with one you only scan a circle).

Comment: @ThePointer The main advantage of the prism scanner (and the only reason I have actually seen one used for beam scanning) is that they scan in transmission and on both axes rather than reflection, so if you must have a very small, narrow optical system where you can't fit the right angle needed for a mirror, then you're usually stuck with the prism scanner.  The downside is that they're relatively slow and the control is complicated.

Comment: @user1850479 Very interesting. Thank you for taking the time to explain this.

Comment: Mirror galvos have been around much linger than laser diodes, so, to some extent, history.  Also, not every type of laser has an inexpensive diode implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Moving mass affecting bandwidth is the main problem. A tiny mirror can have orders of magnitude less moment of inertia than a laser, so can be scanned correspondingly faster. It also gives you twice the deflection for any given angle of turn.

A secondary problem is the conduction of power to the laser. A moving mirror needs no wires.

These problems become magnified if we talk powerful lasers such as used in concert displays, or guide star projectors. A good front surface mirror will not get hot, and can be mounted well away from the heat dissipating laser.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this to give a more comprehensive answer? I'm new to electronics, so I'm not sure what "mass affecting bandwidth" means, and nor do I understand why "conduction of power to the laser" is a problem in this context.

Comment: @ThePointer I've added a bit about better bandwidth meaning faster scanning. I'm not sure what I can add about the power to the laser, I've already said a mirror needs no wires. A laser does need wires. Wires to a moving object need to flex. Wires that flex, break. Wires are heavy (at least, heavier than nothing) which affects bandwidth.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: To the OP, most speakers have wires to the voicecoil (which moves) and it is indeed one of the main failure points for speakers.

Answer (score 2):

> In particular, couldn't we just attach the laser to a servo, as done here and here, and do laser scanning in this way? What benefit does deflection have over using a servo?

You can in principle move the laser, it just isn't very practical in most cases. From your examples I suspect you're thinking of laser pointers or other small diode lasers, moving at very low speeds but it's pretty common that lasers are large and very fragile. For example, on recent system I designed used a 100 lb, liquid cooled laser that needed to be mechanically decoupled from the room vibration on a floated air table, while the scanner spec was 16,000 Hz. Moving something that heavy at that rate is physically impossible. Actually, even moving a tiny laser diode at that speed would also be hard.

This is an extreme case, but you'll run into similar problems even with small diode lasers except at very low speeds, and usually people want to scan as fast as possible. Even then, diode lasers still have collimating optics, and shaking them back and forth on a motor can be complex to tolerance.

> All of the deflection technologies are implemented using mechanical components (such as servos); otherwise, how would we expect them to move?

There are akinetic beam scanners as well, which can reach higher speeds since there is no moving mass. The most common type is the acousto-optical deflector, which uses a sound wave in a lead glass to diffract (rather than reflect) the beam at an electrically controlled angle. There are also electro-optical scanners that modulate refractive index using an external electric field, but these are not very practical in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

A scanning rangefinder isn't just a point rangefinder made to be retargetable so you can slowly move from point-to-point to measure the distance to different targets. They scan to form an image which means they scan fast.

No gears and no reciprocating motion allow for higher reliability and scanning speed. These scan at least 90 degree arcs at least 10Hz. Try moving your back and forth hand like that and just imagine what is happening to whatever you are holding, as well as feeling all the stress.

And no slip rings for 360 degrees scanning, because slip rings suck.